# How to create SimpleDialogueOptions from a list ? | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a list of menus in the form of simpledialogoptions. The method I tried gives me error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#3955f relayoutBoundary=up2
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
```

my code:

```
  List<String> category = ['Not Specified', 'Cats'];

  Future<void> showCategories() async {
    switch (await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            title: Text(
              'Select a Category',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
            ),
            children: <Widget>[
              ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, categoryListIndex) {
                return SimpleDialogOption(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                    title: Text(category[categoryListIndex]),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, category[categoryListIndex]);
                  },
                );
              }),
            ],
          );
        })) {
      case 'Not Specified':
        print('Option 1');
        break;
      case 'Cats':
        print('Option 2');
        break;
    }
  }
```

I tried it with ListView builder it gives me errors. Can someone help me out with an alternative method or to fix this error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with a column like this.

```
  Future<void> showCategories(context) async {
    var result = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          title: Text(
            'Select a Category',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
          ),
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: List.generate(
                category.length,
                (index) {
                  return SimpleDialogOption(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                      title: Text(category[index]),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, category[index]);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );

    switch(result){
      case 'Not Specified':
        print("Option 1");
        break;
      case 'Cats':
        print("Option 2");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if this helps with out having and `itemCount` on your `ListView.builder` it doesn't know how many widgets to render.

```
Future<void> showCategories() async {
    switch (await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            title: Text(
              'Select a Category',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
            ),
            children: <Widget>[
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: categoryListIndex.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, categoryListIndex) {
                return SimpleDialogOption(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                    title: Text(category[categoryListIndex]),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, category[categoryListIndex]);
                  },
                );
              }),
            ],
          );
        })) {
      case 'Not Specified':
        print('Option 1');
        break;
      case 'Cats':
        print('Option 2');
        break;
    }
  }
```